# How to rename parent path in NextJS dynamic routing

Tags: url, routes, next.js

I’m able to use NextJS dynamic routing to build pages. Currently I have the file structure as photo. The url `/apps` shows many apps, `/apps/123` shows the app detail for a single app.

But I want to turn `/apps/123` to `/app/123`, and keep everything else the same. How to achieve that in NextJS?

[Photo of the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWFF1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename the folder `apps` as `app`. That will change the [routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction) too.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar Shahi for answering. I still want the url `/apps` to show a page of apps. But every individual app page should be accessible from the url `app/[id]`. If I rename the folder `apps` as `app`, then the first requirement won't work.

Comment: Then I think you should have an `apps` folder with only index. and an `app` folder with your dynamic `[id]` pages